# How to kill a javascript setTimeout loop

Tags: jquery

I have this loop that works okay:

```
function countdown(counter) {
    x = counter;
    if (x > 0) {
        x--;
        alert(x + "/5");
        if (x > 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                countdown(x);
            }, 500);
        }
    }
};

countdown(6);
```

But I'd like to be able to kill it, and start it again by pressing a button. I'd like to restart the loop, regardless of what number it's on when I press the button.

I've got nowhere over the last few hours.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vtPH/4/

Comment: global state seems to be the only answer.

Comment: Save the return value of `setTimeout` somewhere.  Call `clearTimeout`, then re-call `countdown(6);`.

Comment: Not sure, but setInterval might be better in your case? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval it also has a clear method similar to timeout

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `clearTimeout` [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout)

```
var timeout;
function countdown(counter) {
    x = counter;
    if (x > 0) {
        x--;
        alert(x + "/5");
        if (x > 0) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                countdown(x);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
};
$('input').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    countdown(6);
});
countdown(6);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vtPH/6/)

Comment: Hi, i have used same clearTimeout() function to clear the already running loop. but it still running already created instances. So, after using clearTimeout(), i try to create new instance. Instead of clearing the previous one, it is added as another concurrent loop. Can you please help me on destroy the previous instances?

Answer (score 0):

You should really look at [the documentation for `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#JavaScript_Content).

It returns a *timeout id* that you can use with `clearTimeout` to reset.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign your setTimeout to a variable.

```
var timeout = setTimeout(..
```

Then when needed you can use `clearTimeout(timeout)`.  Make sure your timeout variable is scoped in a way that it can be accessed anywhere you need to access it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an interval for a countdown? Here is an alternative solution ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vtPH/13/)):

```
function Countdown(counter) {
    this.interval = 0;
    this.x = counter;
    console.log(this.x + "/"+counter);
    this.start = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.x--;
            console.log(self.x + "/"+counter);
            if(self.x == 0) self.stop();
        }, 2000);
    };

    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);  
    };
};

var c = new Countdown(7);
c.start();

var c2 = new Countdown(4);

c2.start();
```